# How can I tweak virtual desktops?

Tags: unity, workspaces

The single biggest feature of Ubuntu that I absolutely love is the virtual desktops. The ability to have four different workspaces - one for chat, one for developer tools, one for web tabs, and miscellaneous has basically decoupled me from a second monitor. I can now roam freely with my laptop and still be effective at my job.

But its not perfect and I'd love a chance to tweak it - add more desktops, change the shape, any other options that exist. What is the best way to do this?